# how to parse a specific key in a given string using linux shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a following pattern and would like to parse only one field
between /sys/bus/pci/devices/ and /device

Example 1
Input:
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/device:0x017a

Required output: 
0000:07:00.0

Example 2
Input:
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/device:0x0abc

Required output: 
0000:08:00.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is always that regular, then a simple `cut` command will do the job

```
cut -d/ -f6
```

eg

```
% echo /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/device:0x017a | cut -d/ -f6
0000:07:00.0

% echo /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/device:0x0abc | cut -d/ -f6
0000:08:00.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Input has not a fix number of `/`, you may also use grep with context:

```
$ ... | grep -Po 'devices/\K.*?(?=/device)'
```